# how to convert a video to a MOV file with h264 yuvj420p and pcm u8

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.264

I want to convert some videos to be playable on a Canon digital camera.

The videos from the Canon PowerShot camera have the following specifications:

```
Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 1280x720, 22865 kb/s, 29.97 fps
Audio: pcm_u8 (raw  / 0x20776172), 12000 Hz, mono, u8, 96 kb/s
```

What would the `ffmpeg`-command line look like to produce such videos? Or where can I read about it? I have to tried to find it with `ffmpeg -formats` which gives me a big list of formats. From this and some furter reading in the man page I have come to this command:

```
ffmpeg -i oldmovie.mp4 -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 12000 -ac 1 -vcodec copy -pix_fmt yuvj420p MVI_2655.MOV
```

but it still does not work. The video spec is different.

The video I get is:

```
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x272 [SAR 153:154 DAR 180:77], 326 kb/s
```

but the correct video should have

```
Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 1280x720, 22865 kb/s
```

I think the resolution is not the problem, but the **High** versus **Constrained Baseline**. And the **yuv420p** versus the **yuvj420p**. How do I achieve these specs?

Comment: You can't use '-vcodec copy'. You need to reencode the video track too : ```ffmpeg -i oldmovie.mp4 -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 12000 -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -profile:v baseline MVI_2655.MOV```

Comment: @Ely it's worth writing that up as an answer, perhaps with explanations of the various options. I would myself but you beat me to it! :P

Comment: Can you provide a short sample file from the camera?

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from Ely and bit a further research I have found this command line to produce the exact same format specifications:

```
ffmpeg -i oldmovie.mp4 -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 12000 -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -profile:v baseline -s 1280x720 -r ntsc -colorspace smpte170m -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 MVI_2655.MOV
```

where

- `-vcodec libx264` together with `-profile:v baseline` and `-pix_fmt yuvj420p` sets the video to  **Constrained Baseline** and the pixel format to **yuvj420p**
- `-colorspace smpte170m`, `-color_primaries bt709` and `-color_trc bt709` sets the three pixel format subspecifications after yuvj420p(pc,…), which I’ve found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ffmbc-discuss/jmwDmnhep6E)
- `-r ntsc` sets a framerate of 29.97 (where ntsc is an alias for the framerate)
- `-s 1280x720` scales the video to the same width and height as the original canon video

Now the only difference is the bitrate, which is 4065 kb/s for my ffmpeg-created video and 21588 kb/s for the canon video.

But nevertheless the video still can’t be played on the Canon camera. :-(

Comment: There's probably a `udta` atom in Canon's files that the camera looks for.