# How can I imitate the video codec of a Canon DSLR?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, quicktime, stuck-pixel

I have a Canon EOS Rebel SL1 (100D) with a stuck pixel in the screen that really bothers me out. I'm trying to play one of these ["dead pixel fixer"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjdrMuKpaCI) videos on the camera in order to bring it to life again.

I'm messing around with `ffmpeg` to imitate the Canon's codec, sadly with no success. I'm using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/972853/how-to-convert-a-video-to-a-mov-file-with-h264-yuvj420p-and-pcm-u8) as my start point with some additions (like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg/428039#428039) and [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23741/how-to-prevent-ffmpeg-from-dropping-metadata)) to match the metadata. Here is my current command line:

```
ffmpeg -i reviver.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -movflags use_metadata_tags -metadata creation_time="2019-10-13 22:05:33" -metadata compatible_brands="qt  CAEP" -metadata minor_version="537331968" -metadata com.apple.quicktime.make="Canon" -metadata com.apple.quicktime.model="Canon EOS REBEL SL1" -metadata com.apple.quicktime.rating.user="0.000000" -metadata com.apple.quicktime.author="Anyone" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -profile:v baseline -level:v 5.0 -s 1920x1080 -r ntsc -colorspace bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 MVI_2701.MOV
```

The `ffprobe` output of the resulting file gives me this:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    creation_time   : 2019-10-13 22:05:33
    minor_version   : 537331968
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Canon
    com.apple.quicktime.model: Canon EOS REBEL SL1
    com.apple.quicktime.rating.user: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.author: Anyone
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:35.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2892 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1353 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-14T03:05:33.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.59.102 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-14T03:05:33.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

And this is the output of a video from my Canon DSLR:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Canon
    com.apple.quicktime.model: Canon EOS REBEL SL1
    com.apple.quicktime.rating.user: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.author: Ernesto
    creation_time   : 2019-10-13T19:50:54.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:21.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 89302 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 87729 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-13T19:50:54.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-13T19:50:54.000000Z
```

Despite some *minor* differences, both looks almost the same. But my output file doesn't play on the camera.

My last attempt was [trying to copy the metadata from a video of my DSLR to my fake .MOV](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28599) using `exiftools`. Some extra metadata was actually copied, but seems like it isn't enough for the DSLR.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: While I would expect the camera to handle it your video is at 30fps (29.97) as opposed to 24fps (23.98).

Comment: @Mokubai I've also tried with 24fps, and it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Fair enough. You might also want to change your `-level:v 5.0` to `-level:v 3.0`. 5.0 I thought was a "high" profile setting and it may be the camera doesn't support it.